# What is the rationale for KDE's Neon project?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, kde-neon

I read the KDE Neon FAQ and I simply don't understand the rationale for its existence:

- If the KDE people wanted to provided better/nicer/more up-to-date KDE-related packages, they could just provide an APT repository (which they could call Neon if they like); but they encourage you download ISOs and suggest you *not* switch to Neon via apt.
- If the there's some issue with how Kubuntu packages things, why couldn't the KDE people have interacted with Canonical  / Kubuntu volunteers to resolve it? I mean, it's not like Kubuntu wants to mess up, right?
- Why does KDE even want to tie itself to a single distro (Ubuntu), when in theory it should build and run just fine on any reasonable distro?

Please explain this to me... as a once great fan of KDE and these days not to sure what to think of it.

Comment: Ask the KDE people at https://forum.kde.org/

Comment: @IporSircer: So this is not common knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

Your best information is probably at the FAQ here: https://neon.kde.org/faq
But here are a few more clues:

Based on the FAQs Kubuntu is not recommended for two reasons. First its not actually supported the whole point in using a LTS is that they have a distro that will be supported. The second is that all the work that goes into creating KDE neon replaces all of the work that goes into Kubuntu except with newer software by people more familiar with that software. However the choice to use Ubuntu over Debian or Fedora is questionable but not entirely unreasonable.

That gets us to the next point. Simply getting Kubuntu to to support newer versions of KDE conflicts with Kubuntus goals or at least their governance. KDE neon unties any support issues that might arise from supporting newer software.

To your last point. The FAQ explanation is that this is just one project among many. But I don't see any KDE strobe for Debian and KDE laser for Fedora. Perhaps the KDE developers willing to do this are just Ubuntu fanboys. Or maybe they figure if you're a Fedora or Debian user you can figure out how to get the latest software. They hint at this when they say "We also feel that Ubuntu users will miss out if they do not have up to date KDE software."

Comment: So, you're saying that Kubuntu is not actually LTS-supported by canonical? If that's the case, you could say "Neon is a kind of a properly-LTS Kubuntu but with up-to-date KDE package".

Comment: I think you have it backward. Things like Fedora spins are supported because of how RedHat supports its community project. Canonical doesn't support Kubuntu commercially. It's an unsupported community project. Actually it'd be a fair comparison to say that RHEL is what you'd get not Fedora. But in this case Ubuntu splits this support between a distro that supports KDE and one that does not. Whereas something like spins would work on RHEL.